# Execute SQL Statement stored in table column

Tags: sql, db2

I have insert statement in DB2 database table column and i want to execute that in store procedure

Table:

```
TB_SQL
(
DATA_SQL VARCHAR(12000)
)
```

DATA_SQL column contains INSERT statements. for example :
SELECT * FROM TB_SQL

```
INSERT INTO ADDRESS (COL1, COL2) 
SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM DEMO WHERE TYPE='ADDRESS'
```

How to PREPARE and EXECUTE the INSERT STATEMENT from DATA_SQL Column in DB2 Store Procedure ?

Code I tried:

```
SET v_SQL=
        'SET ?=(
                    SELECT 
                    DATA_SQL
                    FROM TB_SQL
                    WHERE TBNAME='''||v_TBNAME||'''
               )
        ';
        PREPARE SQL_QUERY FROM v_SQL;
        EXECUTE SQL_QUERY ;
```

In reality the above PREPARE AND EXECUTE will only prepare SELECT statement and execute SELECT statement. 
What i want is, I want to execute the statement that comes as output from SELECT statement.

I also have below option to store the INSERT statement again in another variable

```
SET v_SQL=
        'SET ?=(
                    SELECT 
                    DATA_SQL
                    FROM TB_SQL
                    WHERE TBNAME='''||v_TBNAME||'''
               )
        ';
        PREPARE SQL_QUERY FROM v_SQL;
        EXECUTE SQL_QUERY INTO v_INSERT_STATEMENT;
        PREPARE SQL_INSERT FROM v_INSERT_STATEMENT;
        EXECUTE SQL_INSERT;
```

I believe now i have insert statement stored in `v_INSERT_STATEMENT`
And again prepared SQL from variable and then executed. But this is not working.

Comment: this seems straight forward and covered in any book / article about dynamic SQL -- are you running into a specific problem with code you tried?

Comment: Hogan, i updated the original post with what i have tried.

Comment: You have output.  so you need `EXECUTE SQL_QUERY INTO :varname`. varname will now contain the sql -- then you have to prepare and execute that code.

Comment: Hogan, So my approach is correct ?  So PREPARE v_INSERT_STATEMENT; EXECUTE  will work ?  Let me try.

Comment: looks right to me... can't test it right now.

Comment: got it. It is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET v_SQL=
        'SET ?=(
                    SELECT 
                    DATA_SQL
                    FROM TB_SQL
                    WHERE TBNAME='''||v_TBNAME||'''
               )
        ';
        PREPARE SQL_QUERY FROM v_SQL;
        EXECUTE SQL_QUERY INTO v_INSERT_STATEMENT;
        PREPARE SQL_INSERT FROM v_INSERT_STATEMENT;
        EXECUTE SQL_INSERT;
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need two dynamic statements...one static and one dynamic makes much more sense.

```
select data_sql into v_Insert_statement
from tb_sql 
where tbname = v_TBNAME;

PREPARE SQL_INSERT FROM v_INSERT_STATEMENT;
EXECUTE SQL_INSERT;
```